# Should there be commas in these four sentences?

Tags: punctuation, comma

I’ve got these four questions concerning comma placement:

1. > Ich mache jetzt schon mal die Hausaufgaben(,) um sie später nicht machen zu müssen.

Should there be the comma?

2. > Das macht man(,) damit nichts schief geht

Should there be the comma?

3. > Danke(,) Jonas(,) für diese Antwort.

Should there be both of the commas, or just one (or none)?

4. > Ich werde jetzt solange Schafezählen(,) bis ich einschlafe.

Should there be the comma?

Comment: These sentences don’t follow a common pattern. Voting to close as too broad. Ideally, a single question should highlight a *single* issue.

Comment: The OP seems to be looking for somebody who will do his homework. No common pattern, no particular difficulty. Who bother stackexchange with this?

Comment: There is a space missing: "Schafe zählen" are two words.

Comment: … whereas _[schiefgehen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schiefgehen)_ is one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all questions, all commas have to be placed.

The rules for comma placement may be found [here from §71 on page 78 on](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_regeln-woerterverzeichnis_inkl_Nachtraegen.pdf):

> - §74: Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.
>     *Translation*: Dependent clauses are separated by commas, in case of injected clauses surrounded by commas.

This clears question 2 and 4 because `damit nichts schief geht` and `bis ich einschlafe` are dependent clauses.

> §75: Infinitivgruppen grenzt man mit Komma ab, wenn eine der folgenden
>   Bedingungen erfüllt ist.
>   (1) die Infinitivgruppe ist mit um, ohne, statt, anstatt, außer, als
>   eingeleitet
>   (2) [...]
>   *Translation*: Infinitve groups are separated by commas, if one of the following conditions is satisfied:
>   (1) the infinitive group is initiated by `um, ohne, statt, anstatt, außer, als`
>   (2) [...]

This clears question 1 because `um sie später nicht machen zu müssen.` is an infinitive group initiated by `um`.

> §77: Zusätze oder Nachträge grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie ein-
>   geschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.
>   *Translation*: Additions are separated by commas, in case of injections surrounded by commas.

This clears question 3, because `Jonas` is an injected addition.

Comment: Actually, case 3 could also go without both commas. It would be an imperative then, though in most cases one would use an exclamation mark at the end, too.

Comment: @Matthias You're right, but it would also have another meaning.